# How to turn on other unit's heating on the boiler?

Tags: heating

How to turn on other unit's heating on the water heating boiler without the thermostat?

The story goes like this: the tenant goes to trip, and I told her, we need to turn on your heating system as the water pipe may burst due to expansion and contraction during the winter. She reply "I couldn't hand you the key, but you can turn it on in the basement." and therefore the question.

Comment: where is the boiler and where is the valve for the radiator?

Comment: Is this an apt building or possibly a duplex?